# eclipse CDT : Indexer doesn't work with preprocessor setting

Tags: eclipse-cdt, armcc

I'm struggling with immigrate project from eclipse indigo to neon.
I successfully build project in eclipse neon, but indexer doesn't really work perfectly.

The problem is I registered #define in properties > C/C++ build > settings, but indexer doesn't get it's there.

what I've done so far:

1. Check C/C++ General > preprocessor Include paths, macros etc.

   - My define was there under 'CDT managed build setting entries'
   - there was only one option in languages which is [Unspecified]
2. change scability settings

   - some people suggested to change number in  'enable scalability mode when the number of lines in the file is more than' text box as large as I can. so I done it, and no changes.
3. change indexer settings.
   I tried to change options in properties>C/C++ build>Indexer.

   - Skip files larger than : 99999MB
   - Skip included files larger than : 99999MB
   - trying 'Allow heuristic resolution of includes on and off.
   - Build configuration for the indexer : Use active build configuration.
4. rebuild/ freshen all files on rightclick>indexer.

   - Project seem to rebuild, but some of unresolved symbols because of that #define doesn't work.

Once again, my normal build works perfect.
I'm worry about I'm using old ARM plugin for using ARMCC, but I cannot change compiler because it's my companies policy.
If someone figured out how preprocessor can work, please share with me, and if there no way to make indexer compatible with armcc, I'll give up.

Thank you for reading this long question.
And thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Does configuring the macro in `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols` or `C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> CDT User Settings` help?

Comment: @HighCommander4 thank you for your comment. But I've already done with it, and that's why I was succeed to build my project. Actually I set-up gnu-arm compile environment after  this question, and indexer just worked. I think there's compatibility issue with newer version of eclipse and old arm's realview plugin. Maybe I have to edit in gnu-arm mode and compile on the other modes :(

Comment: @GayounHan I am not sure if you have come across http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/ they are plug-ins that sit on top of CDT to make configuring for ARM easier. Perhaps that will help.